# Marginnote Large Fonts are Misaligned from Text

Tags: fonts, margins, geometry, marginnote

I am still in the process of making a similar style kind of book to https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/numerical_analysis_9th.pdf. This mostly includes having section numbers as well as theorems and figure labels in the left margin.

Currently I am using the marginnote package to try and accomplish this however, when the font is large, say using the \huge command or \fontsize the margin notes are misaligned vertically from the text. I was wondering if someone could help me with this, or if I should even be using marginnotes to do this (maybe there is a different better way).

Here is a picture showing the problem.
[image: Problem]

Anywho, here is my MWE class file and corresponding tex file. Thanks.

notes.cls

```
% notes.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{notes}
\LoadClass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\geometry{
    letterpaper,
    left=2in,
    right=1in,
    marginparwidth=1.5in,
    marginparsep=.25in
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\reversemarginpar

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% setup counters for custom sections
\newcounter{ChpCounter}
\newcounter{SecCounter}[ChpCounter]
\newcounter{SubCounter}[SecCounter]
\newcounter{SubSubCounter}[SubCounter]

% Setup counters for side margins
\newcounter{TheoremCounter}[SecCounter]
\newcounter{DefinitionCounter}[SecCounter]
\newcounter{ExampleCounter}[SecCounter]
\newcounter{FigureCounter}[SecCounter]
\newcounter{TableCounter}[SecCounter]

% Insert side margin notes
% Use \side{param}
% param: 
%       Theorem
%       Definition
%       Example
%       Figure
%       Table
\newcommand{\side}[1]{{\marginnote{
\color[HTML]{156EC7} \large \textbf{#1 \theSecCounter.\the\value{#1Counter}}}} \stepcounter{#1Counter}}

% Section bar length
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\mylength}{\marginparwidth}
% \addtolength{\mylength}{\marginparsep}

\newcommand{\zchp}[1]{ 
    \stepcounter{ChpCounter}
    \marginnote{{\textbf {\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont \theChpCounter}}}
    {\textbf{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont #1}}
    \vspace{100px}
    \newline
}

\newcommand{\zsec}[1]{ 
    \stepcounter{SecCounter}
    \stepcounter{TheoremCounter}
    \stepcounter{DefinitionCounter}
    \stepcounter{ExampleCounter}
    \stepcounter{FigureCounter}
    \stepcounter{TableCounter}
    \noindent{\color[HTML]{156EC7}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\rule{\mylength}{3pt}}}
    \marginnote{\textbf{{\fontsize{30}{34}\selectfont \theChpCounter.\theSecCounter}}}
    {\fontsize{30}{34}\selectfont \textbf{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\zsub}[1]{ 
    \stepcounter{SubCounter}
    \marginnote{\theChpCounter.\theSecCounter.\theSubCounter}   
    #1
}

\newcommand{\zsubsub}[1]{ 
    \stepcounter{SubSubCounter}
    \marginnote{\theChpCounter.\theSecCounter.\theSubCounter.\theSubSubCounter}
    #1
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

notes.tex

```
% notes.tex
\documentclass{notes}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\zchp{Chapter}
\zsec{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not think, that `\marginnote` is a good suggestion for this. A simple `\hspace*` with negative value or a `\makebox` to the left would be better. So IMHO this is a [xy-problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449). However you have much more problems, like unwanted spaces because of missing `%` at end of lines, ending groups with loosing font size before end of paragraph, not preventing page breaks after headings. I would recommend to use either a class, that provides heading configuration or a package like `titlesec` to add this feature to a standard class.